# Write into array until it gets full

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I am heading a problem with filling my array with characters from a file. What I want to do is that 
`z = getc(fp)` should write into array until there are no characters in the file OR if there is more characters than array size, it should fill the array and ignore the rest of the characters in file.
When I run this code, it terminates right away. I had `z = getc(fp) != EOF` but it overflew the arrays size when there was more chars that MAX says.

Btw, I have searched for related topic but there was nothing close to it. So please be patient.

```
//MAX is set to 1000

    while( (z = getc(fp)) != '\n' || (z = getc(fp)) < MAX)
            {
                pole[*i] = z;
                (*i)++;
            }
```

Comment: You're reading two characters at each iteration, then saving only the second one!

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking that `*i` is less than `MAX`? And as no ASCII character will be over `127` (or `255` if you use extended ASCII) then the second condition will *always* be true meaning you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @barakmanos if I remove first getc, it terminates after 2-3 seconds but no output.

Comment: `|| (z = getc(fp)) < MAX` --> `&& *i < MAX -1)`

Comment: You should add the relevant pieces of your code into the question. Where are `z`, `i` and `fp` declared? Where are they initialized??? Why on earth are you using a pointer as an index???

Comment: is using pointer as an index wrong? I am new in C so I dont really know all the rules. But my program is working okay with it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two terminal conditions:

- terminate when `i >= MAX` (or continue while `i < MAX`)
- terminate when `feof(fp)` (or continue while `!feof(fp)`)

Terminate when first **or** second condition is met.

Go while first **and** second condition is **NOT** met.

So you want to go on while the *both "second ones" are met*. Thus `i < MAX && !feof(fp)`.

```
z = getch(fp);
*i = 0;
while(*i < MAX && !feof(fp)){
    pole[*i] = z;
    (*i)++;
    z = getch(fp);
}
```

Or as suggested in comment you may also do it like this:

```
*i = 0;
while ((z = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && *i < MAX){
    pole[*i] = z;
    (*i)++;
}
```

Which will strip the duplicate `z = fgetc(fp)` call and is bit more compact.

Comment: No no no, don't put `feof(...)` in a loop condition, as the `EOF` flag will not be set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file, which means the loop will iterate once to many.

Comment: you meant getc ..but thanks now I got it, and its working perfect :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg are you sure that this is issue here? Lets say file is `20B` long, 20 iterations are fine, then in the end of loop `z=getch(fp)` gets called (tries to reach first char outside the file), sets `eof=1` and **then** condition with `feof()` gets called -> everything should be fine.

Comment: Okay, *your* code will handle it okay, but generally it's bad advice. Doing e.g. `while ((z = fgetc(...)) != EOF && *i < MAX)` just seems more natural to me (and you don't have to duplicate code for the input function call).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've added also sample with your condition. I **would** be glad if you could elaborate more on why it's *generally bad advice*  (I know it can be easily misused but it doesn't seem to justify calling it "bad practice"). Feel free to add any reference/examples to my answer showing why is dangerous/bad practice.

Comment: Thanks guys for advice, I am just a newbie into C so anything can help me. Btw, your edited code is missing opening bracket for while.

Answer (score 0):

your loop right now, is checking if the getc(fp) is different from '\n'. As long as it is different from  '\n', it will never check if the second part of the while condiction.

the correct way to deal with this, if I understood what you want to do would be

```
i = 0
z = getc(fp)
while (z != '\n' && i < MAX)
 {
    pole[i] = z
    i++
    z = getc(fp)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really can use `\n` to detect the end of the file, and that your array has `MAX` elements:

```
 z = getc(fp);
 while( (z != '\n') && (*i < MAX) )
    {
        pole[*i] = z;
        (*i)++;
        z = getc(fp);
    }
```